# SQL Query to exclude duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having problems writing some code for my workplace to eliminate duplicate records that appear in a query.

The current query outputs:

```
ID
Name
RelationID
RelationName
RelationDescription
Year
ModifiedDate
ModifiedBy
```

The problem I am having is that the `ModifiedDate(datetime)` column sometimes has multiple modifications on the same day, therefore you get a duplicate record displayed when you execute the query.

I have tried using `SELECT DISTINCT, GROUP BY, WHERE` statements to filter down year etc. `ModifiedDate = convert(varchar(10), ModifiedDate, 102)` to break the modifiedDate and time into separate columns (cannot filter by this as some modifications have been made on the same day at similar times) and have tried different methods to try and filter the column `RelationID` so it only displays one record but none of it has worked.

I am wondering if anyone could please help me to filter the column `RelationID` to only display the latest modified? I have trawled the Internet for days but I just can't get it to work.

Query currently looks like this:

My original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID, Name, RelationID, RelationName, RelationDescription, Year, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy
FROM table1, table2
WHERE Year = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND ModifiedDate IS NOT NULL
```

OUTPUT:

```
123, Dave, 321, Sarah, 2018, 2015-12-01 09:47:36.347
123, Dave, 321, Sarah, 2018, 2015-12-01 09:47:36.347
```

Table 1 and Table 2 are inner joined by RelationID.
ModifiedDate and ModifiedBy are on Table 1.

Thank you for your patience - please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Posting Sample Data and Table create statement will help people to answer this fast.

Comment: Why did you tag with MySQL when your code appears to be SQL Server?

Comment: Apologies - I am new to this. I’ll remove the tag sorry.

Comment: OK...if you had just a single table, I think my query should be working.  Do some of the column names appear in more than one of the three tables?  Also note that you are doing a cross join.  You probably want to have a join condition between the three tables.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have edited the above question.
Table 1 and Table 2 are inner joined by RelationID. ModifiedDate and ModifiedBy are on Table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You can use CTE and Row Number and filter the data by the highest modified time
See the below query

;with CTE 
AS
(SELECT ID, Name, RelationID, RelationName, RelationDescription, [Year], ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition by RelationID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) RN
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.RelationID = Table2.RelationID
)
Select * from CTE
where RN = 1
```

Comment: Thanks so much this has solved my issue! A week of work - your a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Try this , using CTE

```
WITH TEMP AS
(
  SELECT RELATIONID,MAX(MODIFIEDDATE) MDATE FROM TABLENAME
   GROUP BY RELATIONID
)
SELECT A.* FROM TEMP T
INNER JOIN TABLENAME A
ON A.RELATIONID=T.RELATIONID AND A.MODIFIEDDATE=T.MDATE
```

Comment: The problem I am having is that sometimes some of the records are listed twice at the same datetime modified. I am wondering if there is a way to filter by the RelationID column as well so that if SQL sees two entries with matching RelationIDs it only lists it once.

Answer (score 0):

The query below displays only the latest modified per RelationID. An OUTER APPLY is basically an OUTER JOIN to which you can apply other filters, like in this case a TOP 1 to only get the last modified record.

```
SELECT
    [ID]
    ,[Name]
    ,[RelationID]
    ,[RelationName]
    ,[RelationDescription]
    ,[Year]
    ,[ModifiedDate]
    ,[ModifiedBy]
FROM
    [table2]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT
        TOP 1
        [ModifiedDate]
        ,[ModifiedBy]
    FROM
        [table1]
    WHERE
        [table2].[RelationID] = [table1].[RelationID]
    ORDER BY
        [ModifiedDate] DESC
) [table1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this kind of construct:

```
SELECT ID, Name, RelationID, RelationName, RelationDescription, Year, ModifiedDate, ModifiedBy
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.RelationID = Table2.RelationID
WHERE ModifiedDate = (
    SELECT MAX(ModifiedDate) FROM Table1 AS TableX 
    WHERE Table1.ID = TableX.ID -- and other columns as necessary
 )
```

Comment: Could you please explain the Table1 AS Table2 part?

Comment: `AS` creates an alias, so you can refer to Table1 a second time, as if it is another table. This allows `WHERE Table1.ID = Table2.ID` which establishes a correlated subselect - the rows returned from the subselect are related to the main select in some significant way. In this case, it limits the subselect to the rows with the same `ID` (but different `modifieddate` per the question). We then select the `MAX(ModifiedDate)` so that we get only one row returned. Then the main query will only return the one row for each `ID` which has that `MAX`   value of `ModifiedDate`.

Comment: Sorry, I referred to `Table2` in the comment above, when I should have called it something else like `TableX` to distinguish it from your tables. Please read it as such.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have tried this method but am getting an error: 'An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.'

Referring to the SELECT MAX line. I am not really sure why, am working on fixing it but would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Fixed it, but now it only displays 2 records last edited in 2018. I was hoping to get the max modified date of any of the records no matter the year, as some of them were last modified in other years.
I was also hoping to filter the column RelationID so that if there are two of the same records it only lists one of them.